# Controlling and managing a complex program flow in C#

Tags: c#, control-flow

I have a program flow that is quite complex, with a lot of different possibilities. How can this be programmed correctly, is there any standardized method of converting this into decent C# code? With decent I mean not one giant method full of if/else/goto statements.

Will this always be some kind of if/else construction or can we utilize a state machine/automaton? I'm not sure how to get started here.

[image: Flow]

Comment: Well, this is what namespaces, classes and functions are for. Your state diagram isn't so complicated, its just shows how to process a login attempt, with validation.

Answer (score 3):

You are over complicating this.

Note that many of the nodes in your diagram are the same function. After a quick analysis you want some classes with interfaces something like this

```
// This is your credentials type
class Credentials : ICredentials
{
    static ICredentials Load();
    static void Save(ICredentials credentials, IPin pin);
    static void Delete(ICredentials credentials);
    bool Validate();
    bool CheckPin(IPin pin);
}

class Pin : IPin
{
    static IPin Validate(string pin);
}

static class Internet
{
    static bool Available { get; }
}
```

The rest, and the majority, of the work involves implmenting the GUI.

---

**Additionally**

Note that the "Credentials Still Valid?" "No" choice should feed back to "Ask For Credentials". It doesn't make sense to to create new credentials without a pin.

Comment: The GUI should invoke each action, observe and display the results. The GUI should never implement domain specific, or business work. Using an exception (and handling on the UI) if your internet connection fails and then displaying the diaglogue may be better than checking the pre-condition in your implementation.

Comment: @Gusdor agreed, the best way of doing that depends on the UI you need to create, who will be using it and what for, and other factors like, the balance between maintainability, extensibility and pragmatism.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider a workflow solution to this. They have a steep learning curve but once mastered, such a complex flow will be managed with ease.

[Basic setup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489463.aspx)

[Details on workflow designing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489396.aspx)

Ditching console: [Simple app using Windows Workflow and winforms NOT console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523694/simple-app-using-windows-workflow-and-winforms-not-console)

[Next step would be passing parameters, I suppose.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f5aefe65-f2b4-4286-b0d9-9bee3b37fba2/passing-parameters-into-the-workflow)

So, You create a workflow in the designer. Control all you input and output arguments that will be fed to and expected from the workflow. You launch the workflow from a console app or any app. and th within the workflow, your activities can be exactly like your flow images you shared.

I personally had a hard time to catch up with workflow foundation but the system I'm working on cannot be maintained without a workflow approach and after about a week of tutorials, I'm glad I learned it.

And it also goes without saying that workflow foundation is NOT the solution to every software. In fact, it may complicate a design beyond recovery if not used properly or without well thought architecture.

@Bas Brekelmans, I saw your flow and I immediately knew the Workflow FOundation can help you. I'll help out as much as I can.

Good Luck

Comment: Especially targeting the FlowChart activity in WF4. It will allow exactly this kind of flow.


http://www.develop.com/flowwf4

Comment: That Switch example @Boranas posted ^... I had a long struggle with it in my case. I think I grew two years older in 5 days before figuring out the 1 vs. "1"

Comment: Workflows does make for a nightmarish debugging.

Comment: As you said. "a steep learning curve". But I've used it for quite a while. When used in a stateless mode(without persistence), I've got not complains. Got a ton to complain about the persistence and appFabric

Answer (score 0):

Your code as a whole will will always express all the conditional (if/else) logic you have. But what you want to do is to have those questions dealt with separately, rather than all in one big block.

For example, the question of whether a PIN number is valid is the responsibility of a class that validates PIN numbers. The question of which screen to go to after a PIN has been found to be valid could be the responsibility of a class relating to navigation.

So one simple way of structuring this would be:

- **A number of classes relating to your business logic:**

  - Credentials
  - Login Session (responsible for counting attempts, etc.)
  - Pin Validator
  - Credentials validator
  - PIN complexity requirements checker
  - Internet
  - Credentials Storer
- **A number of Screen classes**, making up your GUI.
- **A Navigator class**, which is responsible for selecting which screen to display, based on the state of your business objects. So
  this is your 'state machine'. It might well have a large-ish switch
  or if statement in it, but it's not doing all the logic in your whole
  app - just moving between screens - so it's not the worst thing in
  the world.

  ***Or*** if you don't like this single 'navigator' idea, you could give each screen a ViewModel that knew only about the business
  objects in needed for that screen, and was responsible for navigation
  from that screen only. In this way, the bahaviour of your state
  machine is distributed between different classes.